# How to conditionally delete node using xslt?

Tags: java, xslt

I am trying to conditionally delete a node based on a parameter.

Sample File:

```
    <A>
        <B>
            <C>Student Node</C>
            <C>Teacher Node</C>
        </B>
    </A>
```

Output File:

Param=1

```
    <A>      
        <B>
            <C>Student Node</C>
        </B>
    </A>
```

Param=0

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C>Teacher Node</C>
    </B>
</A>
```

Here is my current xslt attempt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:param name="preview_type"></xsl:param>
  
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$preview_type = 0">
     <xsl:template match="/A/B/C[text()='Student Node']"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:template match="/A/B/C[text()='Teacher Node']"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Currently, I get the error:

```
SystemId Unknown; Line #13; Column #15; xsl:choose is not allowed in this position in the stylesheet!
```

Any help would be great. I think I am missing some concept about templates/Xslt.

GC_

Comment: The param looks more like you want to _select_ the element specified  by position rather than delete it. What is the logic behind it?

Comment: @zx485 For condition 1, I want to delete on tag, for condition 2, I want to delete the other tag.

Comment: @zx485 I am using the empty template to delete the element.  There is no copy in the empty template tags.

Comment: But your question includes three states: `0`) In the xsl:when and `1` and `2` in the `param` examples.

Comment: zx485 Sorry, I could see how that would throw you. The two states are 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XSLT-1.0 solution that works with native Java XSLT support is the following. It is more complicated, because XSLT-1.0 does not support parameters in template's match rules.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="preview_type" />
  
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="A/B">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$preview_type = 0">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="C[text()!='Student Node']"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="C[text()!='Teacher Node']"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Testing this this morning, but I think this is what I am looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2 or later you could use e.g. `<xsl:template match="/A/B/C[.='Student Node'][$preview_type = 0]"/>`. I think in XSLT 1 the variable reference in a match pattern is not allowed so you would need to move any logic into a template, any `xsl:template` needs to be a top-level child of the `xsl:stylesheet` root element.

Comment: I tried wrapping the choose in a template, but then I got error which I think meant no template inside templates.

Comment: When I did what you described, I got: SystemId Unknown; Line #16; Column #144; xsl:template is not allowed in this position in the stylesheet!

Comment: I posted the line `<xsl:template match="/A/B/C[.='Student Node'][$preview_type = 0]"/>` saying it will do with XSLT 2 and later and also pointed out that any `xsl:template` (that means that snippet as well) needs to be a child of the `xsl:stylesheet`. So no idea what you tried but what I suggested will certainly not give the error you mentioned in the original question as well as in the comment.